# Extract numbers from a code

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following code, and I need to get the numbers and save them in a row,

```
<div class="F-temperatura">
<p>Temperatura: <span class="min">5º</span><span
class="max">14º</span>
--
<div class="F-temperatura">
<p>Temperatura: <span class="min">4º</span><span
class="max">12º</span>
--
<div class="F-temperatura">
<span class="min">2º</span><span class="max">11º</span>
</div>
--
<div class="F-temperatura">
<span class="min">2º</span><span class="max">12º</span>
</div>
--
<div class="F-temperatura">
<span class="min">8º</span><span class="max">16º</span>
</div>
--
<div class="F-temperatura">
<span class="min">2º</span><span class="max">10º</span>
</div>
```

I need to get

```
5,14,4,12,2,11,2,12,8,16,2,10
```

I have uses this commands to get number 5, in this case my file is called dada.txt

```
awk 'NR == 2' dada.txt | cut -d '<' -f 3 | cut -d '>' -f 2 | tr -d 'º'
```

it works well, for example I get number 5,... but it is a tedious work if I have to extract many numbers because I have to modify NR for min temperature and more for max temperature... any idea to get them in a cleaner and faster way in bash?

Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, to extract all numbers without context, one per line

```
grep -oE "[0-9.]+" file
```

if you want the to be comma separated, pipe to `... | paste -sd,`

Comment: thanks, and if I want to save them in a row and separated by commas?

Comment: sometimes I have negative temperature... if I do grep -oE "[0-9.-]+" file, then I get, -,2,8,--,-,2,6,--,-,-1,2,--,-,0,4,--,-,1,5,--,-,-5,2
how can I avoid the - that doesn't correspond negative numbers?

Comment: the regex is very simplistic.  You can define a more comprehensive one, for example `\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*`